# What could be happened if at a dismissModalViewController call doesn't follow up a dealloc call?

Tags: objective-c

I have a strange problem. 
I set up a simple system that present modally a view. When i call dismiss for this modal view, the view disappear correctly but neither dealloc or viewDidUnload calls are done.

Here the code to make the view appear:

```
-(IBAction) spendBtnTap{
    SpendVC *spendVC = [[SpendVC alloc] initSpendWithContext:self.context]; 
    spendVC.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:spendVC animated:YES];
    [spendVC release];
}
```

And the code to make the view disappear (from SpendVC.m):

```
-(void) pressBackBtn{   
    [self.delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And for dealloc in SpendVC ... i just added this output (But nothing happen in my console log...):

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"spend dealloc");
}
```

In my application i have other button set this way... and they work correctly ... what can i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the UIViewController docs:

> viewDidUnload is called during low-memory conditions
>   when the view controller needs to
>   release its view and any objects
>   associated with that view to free up
>   memory

So it's not likely to be called.

As for dealloc, is something else retaining SpendVC?

Comment: Uhm no... the view is created in function spendBtnTap  and doesn't communicate with other areas.

Comment: Terry you are right. I define a delegate property in another part of code with "Retain" and not wit "Assign" so i create a circular reference. Thank you i accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to know,

I encountered a similar problem the last week. On my last project i found that the ***-(void)dealloc*** method was not called after the **dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:** message.

I was in stuck for some hours and then i found the solution. In my case, the problem was due to a scheduledTimer that i triggered somewhere in the viewcontroller.

Be sure to disable all timers before calling **dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:**. I solved as follow:

```
- (void)doneDidPressed {
    if(startTimer) {
        [startTimer invalidate];
        [startTimer release];
        startTimer = nil;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added another test in disappear function (that is correctly called) to check retain count with :

```
NSLog(@"%d",[self retainCount]);
```

It returns 2 ..

I found that in viewDidLoad of SpendVC if i remove this code the retain is correctly set to 1 and after dismiss dealloc is call correctly.

```
//Setup category list
self.cats = [[CatSelectVC alloc]initWithContext:self.context];
self.cats.delegate = self;
self.cats.view.center = CGPointMake(160, 160);
[self.view addSubview:self.cats.view];
```

where is incremented the retain in this code ? self.cats.delegate = self ? in this case what i have to do to release all correctly ?

Comment: The problem is that i have a circular reference on CatSelecVC delegate.. i define delegate property with retain and not with assign. .... what a fail.